# Kaggle data display widget

Tags: visualization, summary, kaggle

Kaggle has a new [widget](https://www.kaggle.com/kaggle/kaggle-survey-2018#SurveySchema.csv) for displaying the sample data. This is a beautiful display of data and also crunches the numbers, text in an easy to view format. How can I create a similar widget for displaying my datasets. I can host it on a webpage.